# Incorrect HTML content in Chromedriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have several tests that write HTML code to a temp directory on a CentOS 7 box and then have Chromedriver load them up to do some basic tests on them.  In this example I am writing the HTML code:

```
<html><body><form>        <label for="text">Text</label>
        <input type="text" id="text"></form></body>
```

However when I get the HTML content via  `getAttribute('innerHTML')` I get this

`<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,
                                 maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <title i18n-content="title">file:///tmp/formJbDsBv</title>
...`

which is clearly not the code I wrote.  The log file on the Selenium side is

`09:45:03.980 INFO - Executing: [get: file:///tmp/formJbDsBv])
09:45:04.084 INFO - Done: [get: file:///tmp/formJbDsBv]`

But, of course, the test works locally and on a virtual machine, but not on my test box, which runs using Xvfb.

Plus, the technique I use works on about a hundred other tests.

Comment: Is your code present anywhere in the file at all?

Comment: I had already answered the question below but I can't close the question for two days.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know *why* this solves it, but adding `.html` to the end of the filename made it work.  This is really weird because some of the tests that passed did not have `.html` at the end of their filename.  Weird, but it's working now.